# android studio trying to start an unexistring activity

Tags: android

I installed android studio in a usb flash drive because i work on different computers and i don't always wanted to install it. Recently i started it on an
computer that just a week ago worked but when i run the project the IDE try to 
run an activity that i've deleated in other computer. I have tried to 
rebuild the project, delete the *.idea* and *.gradle* folder, disable instant run. Nothing of those success. What can i do?

**Error message:**

```
Error while executing: am start -n "bonfra04.com.application/bonfra04.com.application.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=bonfra04.com.application/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {bonfra04.com.application/bonfra04.com.application.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

Now MainActivity does not exist any more.

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="bonfra04.com.application">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/GameTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Launcher">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Game"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".ScoreViewer"></activity>
</application>
```

**Directory structure:**

[image]

Comment: I am confused. Did you deleted the activity, committed the code and push? is the code also in the usb?

Comment: @Kanekotic Android studio is installed in the USB and also the code is inside it. In one computer i've deleted an activity (also updated the manifest) and in another i runned the code but the compiler still try to run the activity that i've deleated

Comment: It would help us if you post your manifest and/or your directory structure so we can better analyze what's wrong. But I think there's some Mos configuration in your manifest. Try searching for `MainActivity` using android studio's search functionality then delete or replace that line.

Comment: @jasperagrante just posted. I've searched for _MainActivity_ using android studio but it only found the _makeMainActivity_ method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Studio at the left of the green Run button, drop down the "**app**" list and press 
"**Edit Configurations**".   
In the "General" tab check the "**Launch options**".  
 You must see "**Default Activity**". If not select it and click OK.

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest, I bet this activity is still defined as a launcher activity.